# Displaying ArcScene animation (*.asa) in Powerpoint?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, animation

I just used ArcScene to make an animation clip, whose format is .asa.

Is there a way for me to put it into PowerPoint for the sake of presentation?

Answer (score 2):

I tend to export them as a movie format then embed that into the powerpoint. The .asa file is meaningless without the the original ArcScene document.

[image]